# WsSource OUT of Range

Tags: excel, vba

Have this code working initially but when I run it again it gave me this error "ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AccountsAuditlogReview")=< SUbscript out of range>. Thanks

```
Dim wsSource, wsExtract As Worksheets

    Set wsSource = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("AccountsAuditLogReview")* This one errors out "SUbscript out of range"
    Set wsExtract = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("IndvAcctReview")
    
    Rows("5:5").Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Selection.AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$JO$100000").AutoFilter Field:=4, Criteria1:="*GRP*"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$JO$100000").AutoFilter Field:=5, Criteria1:="No"
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$5:$JO$100000").AutoFilter Field:=7, Criteria1:="Prior"
    
    wsSource.Range("A6:CD300000").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
    wsExtract.Cells(2, 1).PasteSpecial
     
    ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
```

Tried starting a new workbook with the same code but still not working.

Comment: `Dim wsSource As Worksheet, wsExtract As Worksheet`. Use `Worksheet`, not `Worksheets`, and specify the type for every variable.

Comment: The error means that there is no sheet with that name in `ThisWorkbook`. Check spelling and ensure no leading or trailing spaces in the sheet name.

Comment: It worked last Friday but when I tried today it will not run. I check the spelling and everything but no luck finding it. Here is the entire code that I want to complete.

Comment: Is there a way to attached file here?